Are hot-air balloons regulated similar to jet aircraft?
Can conventional hot air balloons be considered aircraft as far as regulations are concerned? I mean, they do fly in the air, can ascend into the sky and can land, and also can navigate. But it doesn't have wings.
I want to know if the safety regulations on hot air balloons are similar or equal to normal jet aircraft. Is there any restrictions on how hot air balloons should be maintained and piloted? Are they similar to those restrictions imposed on jet aircraft?

It depends on what you really mean. Airspace is regulated (aviation), but for (wild) birds and weather ;-) It doesn't depend on the type of aircraft. For construction, certification, operation there may be different/simplified rules (light aviation, shutes/para, gliders, etc.), but the general principles are the same.

slightly related: What would be the process to approve a minimal, standardized flight recorder for commercial balloons?

Not all aircraft have wings. Helicopters have rotors, dirigibles have helium, some craft have rockets, lifting bodies just omit the wings.
Large balloons are regulated, similar to other aircraft. Here is FAA's list of balloon regulations for the US: https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/balloons/balloons_regs
